# Map in map : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I have these datas :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test1",
        "secondary": [
            "testS1", "testS2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test2",
        "secondary": [
            "testS3", "testS4"
        ]
    }
]
```

I map all exercices from a json file, and now I wish to loop `props.exercices.secondary` of each object.
Here is my try :

```
export default function AllExos(props) {
    return <div>
        {props.exercices.map(exo => {
            return <div key={exo.name}>
                <div>
                     <h2>{exo.id}</h2>
                     <p>Display secondary :
                            {exo.secondary.map(k => {
                                return <span key={k}>{k}</span>
                            })}
                     </p>
                 </div>
             </div>
        })}
    </div>
}
```

I don't understand why I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. I am looping in the 'props.exercices', right ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The problem mostly isn't in the code you've shown, it's in the code **using** `AllExos`. It's either A) not passing `exercices` to the component (or passing `undefined` for it), or B) passing an array for `exercices` where the elements either don't have a `secondary` property or have one that's `undefined` (depending on which `map` call is throwing the error). The solution is to ensure you pass an array in each of those places, or update `AllExos` to handle it if it gets `undefined` in one of those places.

Comment: Check wether props.exercises is an array or not

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your help. I wonder Why ? because exo.id display a div for each exo. Why looping an array in each object would not work in this case ?

Comment: @johbzr - It *does* work, provided `exo.secondary` is an array. Apparently, sometimes, it's `undefined` instead.

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth props.exercices in an Array with 2 Objects inside

Comment: @johbzr - There are [**several previous questions about this exact thing**](/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+reading+map). The answer is the same: Either ensure that the thing you're calling `.map` on isn't `undefined` by fixing it at the source, or put a guard on it so you don't try to call `map` on `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh ok I see now ! Thank you. Your explanation made me think of exo.secondary?.map and it works. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional chaining.

```
props?.exercices?.map(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition props.exercices && props.exercices.length > 0 &&

```
 export default function AllExos(props) {
    return <div>
        {props.exercices && props.exercices.length > 0 && 
          props.exercices.map(exo => {
            return <div key={exo.name}>
             <div>
                 <h2>{exo.id}</h2>
                 <p>Display secondary :
                        {exo.secondary.map(k => {
                            return <span key={k}>{k}</span>
                        })}
                 </p>
              </div>
          </div>
       })}
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Same problem. If i display only exo.id, it displays the 2 objects. But if I loop on ```secondary```, always this error

Comment: what is output of props.exercices ? Can you console the output .

Comment: @KhandkerAshikMahmud - This issue [is already well-covered here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+reading+map), there's no need to go into it further.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for response.